# bluetoothchat application showing errors

Tags: android, bluetooth, chat

I am trying to run a sample bluetooth chat application onto my smartphone (running Android 2.3). The target build project in Eclipse uses Android API level 10

```
the same project includes this in the manifest:

<uses-sdk minSdkVersion="6" android:targetSdkVersion="10"  />
```

How do I get around this problem? Any Idea

These are my console errors

```
  2012-05-09 12:30:09 - BluetoothChat] Android Launch!
  [2012-05-09 12:30:09 - BluetoothChat] adb is running normally.
  [2012-05-09 12:30:09 - BluetoothChat] Performing     com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat activity launch
 [2012-05-09 12:30:09 - BluetoothChat] Automatic Target Mode: Several compatible targets.   Please select a target device.
[2012-05-09 12:30:13 - BluetoothChat] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2012-05-09 12:30:13 - BluetoothChat] Device API version is 10 (Android 2.3.3)
[2012-05-09 12:30:13 - BluetoothChat] Uploading BluetoothChat.apk onto device 'emulator-5556'
[2012-05-09 12:30:14 - BluetoothChat] Installing BluetoothChat.apk...
[2012-05-09 12:30:21 - BluetoothChat] Success!
[2012-05-09 12:30:21 - BluetoothChat] Starting activity com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat on device emulator-5556
[2012-05-09 12:30:23 - BluetoothChat] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.android.BluetoothChat/.BluetoothChat }
```

And logcat showing these errors

```
  05-09 06:53:04.284: W/dalvikvm(435): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-09 06:53:04.524: E/AndroidRuntime(435): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 06:53:04.524: E/AndroidRuntime(435): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.BluetoothChat/com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android.BluetoothChat-2.apk]
05-09 06:53:04.524: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
05-09 06:53:04.524: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-09 06:53:04.524: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-09 06:53:04.524: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-09 06:53:04.524: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-09 06:53:04.524: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-09 06:53:04.524: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-09 06:53:04.524: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 06:53:04.524: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-09 06:53:04.524: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-09 06:53:04.524: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-09 06:53:04.524: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-09 06:53:04.524: E/AndroidRuntime(435): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android.BluetoothChat-2.apk]
05-09 06:53:04.524: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
05-09 06:53:04.524: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
05-09 06:53:04.524: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
05-09 06:53:04.524: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-09 06:53:04.524: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
05-09 06:53:04.524: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  ... 11 more
05-09 06:57:27.854: I/Process(435): Sending signal. PID: 435 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your **classpath** and **project.properties** file of your Eclipse project, I thought it was not set properly.
Try this way, using information of these files from a normal project that you have created before. Maybe it could help.

Comment: autobot_101, Thanks for the reply and  my project propertirs file is showing this  target=android-10

Comment: check .project  (PROJECT file) in your project also.Sometimes, your project could use <linkedResources>  in this file, when using on different computers, you need to change these lines to point to correct resources.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android.BluetoothChat-1.apk]  WHAT IS THIS ERROR?